# Jade Templates - Dynamic Attributes

Tags: templates, pug

I want to create attributes on the fly for some html elements.

In my case I'd like to set (or not) a disabled attribute according to `user.role`.

So, if `user` has permission to edit some field, I do not want to put disabled attribute on the element. Otherwise, I do want it.

I know that I can do this with these approaches:

#### - Approach 1 - Use Conditionals

```
if (user.role === 1)
   input(type='text', name='foo')
else
   input(type='text', name='foo', disabled)
```

#### - Approach 2 - Plain HTML

```
- var disabledAttr = (user.role === 1) ? "disabled" : "";
| <input type="text" name="foo" #{ disabledAttr} />
```

Approach 1 is bad because I need to repeat some code. With Approach 2 I do not need to repeat code but I have to use plain HTML instead of Jade markup.

I tried something like this:

```
input(type='text', name='foo', #{ disabledAttr} )
```

But jade generates the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" disabledattr="" />
```

Any better idea?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Jade is quite clever when it needs to figure out how to render attributes. You can render your disabled attribute using this single line of jade markup

```
input(type='text', name='foo', disabled=role!==1)
```

Comment: Same applies for example for `select`:

    `select( name="filter" )
        option( value="all" selected=(selected === 'all') ) All
        option( value="articles" selected=(selected === 'articles') ) Articles`

Answer (score 9):

You can to use a bunch of attributes in a conditional way:

```
input(type='text')&attributes(user.role === 1 ? {'disabled': 'true'} : {'class': 'admin', 'ng-model': 'vm.model.name', 'ng-click': 'vm.click()'})
```

Comment: This really helpful incase we don't want to add attribute instead of adding with default value false, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This syntax works for me:

```
input(placeholder!="<%= translate('Add new item') %>")
```

where translate is a function that returns translated text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attributes` helper functions provided by pug globally. I'll not explain the meaning of the variables as they are meaningful.

Below an example of a **mixin** in pug whose goal is to build a *menu link*

```
mixin menu-link(menuName, href, currentURI)
    a.menu-link(href=href)&attributes(href === currentURI ? {"aria-current": "page"} : null)
        span= menuName
```

which will result (if currentURI matches) in :

```html
<a class="menu-link" href="/home aria-current="page">
    <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

source: https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#attributes

`currentURI` variable can also be set as [*global before rendering*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49708861/18075950) and therefore not having to specify an additional argument on the mixin.